# Need javascript code

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript code because I want to remove the class w3-spin in this id="imgg" when i pause an audio element...

```
<div style="width:100%;height:150px;">
<img id="imgg" class="w3-spin img-circle" src="Pic/sky.jpg"   style="width:44%;height:149px;">
<img id="imgg" class="w3-spin img-circle" src="Pic/b.png" style="width:20%;height:75px;top:85px;left:150px;position:absolute;">
</div>
 <audio id="audio" controls loop autoplay style="width:100%;" onclick="pause()">
    <source src="<?php echo $row['Song']?>" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

my javascript..

```
<script> 
    var player = document.getElementById("audio"); 
    var imgg1 = document.getElementById("imgg"); 
    function pause() { 
      player.pause();
      imgg1.removeClass("w3-spin");
      } 
</script>
```

Comment: Your html is invalid. You should not have multiple elements with the same id. Also, what is your question?

Comment: You need javascript code, We need to see what you have tried

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a place to find freelancers. Try Upwork, Elance, or something like that.

Comment: Google for finding an element by id/class and then removal. It can vary if you're using a library vs straight js.

Comment: thanks for replying sir. Lets change the 2nd id to imgg2. Can you help me to make a javascript code to my problem?

Comment: <script> 
    var player = document.getElementById("audio"); 
    var imgg1 = document.getElementById("imgg"); 
    function pause() { 
    player.pause();imgg1.removeClass("w3-spin");
} 
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event you should be listening to when an `audio` element is paused is [`pause`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/pause).

As with play, it's (you guessed it) [`play`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/play).

Check [media events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events) list on MDN for a list of possible event you can listen to for `audio` element.

Here's an example.
Added red background color to `.w3-spin` to help illustrate the class name.

```js
var audioPlayer = document.getElementById("audio");
var imgg = document.getElementById("imgg");
audioPlayer.onpause = function() {
  imgg.className = imgg.className.replace(/\bw3-spin\b/g, "");
};
audioPlayer.onplay = function() {
  if (imgg.className.indexOf("w3-spin") === -1) {
    imgg.className = imgg.className + " w3-spin";
  }
};
```

```css
.w3-spin {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div style="width:100%;height:150px;">
<img id="imgg" class="w3-spin img-circle" src="Pic/sky.jpg"   style="width:44%;height:149px;">
<img id="imgg2" class="w3-spin img-circle" src="Pic/b.png" style="width:20%;height:75px;top:85px;left:150px;position:absolute;">
</div>
 <audio id="audio" controls loop autoplay style="width:100%;">
    <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/2/26/Europe_-_The_Final_Countdown.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Thankyou sir I have an idea now :) helps me a lot thanks you again :)